# How to override base classes\structs such as int, string?

Tags: c#, reflection, decompiling, il

To reduce downvotes: (Skippable at first)

> I am aware that this question sounds pointless and\or weird. I am creating JIT that takes C# code compiles it with csc.exe, extracts the IL and parallize it into CUDA, and I want to override some of the things in C#.

How override base things such as `int`\ `string`?
I tried:

```
class String { /* In namespace System of course */
    BasicString wrap_to;
    public String( ) {
        wrap_to = new BasicString( 32 ); // capacity
    }
    public String( int Count ) {
        wrap_to = new BasicString( Count );
    }
    public char this[ int index ] {
        get { return wrap_to[ index ]; }
        set {
            if ( wrap_to.Handlers != 1 )
                wrap_to = new BasicString( wrap_to );
            wrap_to[ index ] = value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
... // not in namespace System now
class Test {
    public static void f(string s) { }
}
```

But when I tried:

```
Test.f( new string( ) );
```

It error'd `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.String' to 'string'`. I tried moving my `System.String` to just `string` in the global scope and it error'd on the class itself. Any ideas how? I think somehow it could help if I can compile my `.cs` files without that `mscorlib.dll`, but I can't find a way to do it.

Even a way to reach to csc.exe source code may help. (This is critical.)

Comment: Well the problem you currently have is your version of `String` can't be implicitly converted to standard `string` type, they are 2 completely separate types. You can, however, fix this by overriding the [implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) operator.

Comment: @James `string` is the original string object of C#, I want to override it. If I will convert it to that `original string object` I won't be able to use my new customized string and I will lose the new information I want to introduce in my new string class. (You missed the point maybe.)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky, you can use your new type all you want, but you won't be able to pass it to code that was compiled to expect the original `System.String` type. After all, that code was compiled before your type was ever written -- how do you expect it to know how to work with your type? You would have to recompile `mscorlib` and everything else to use your string type instead of `System.String`.

Comment: If you are fine to have own "integer" type instead of `int` you can take a look on `BigInteger` to see what is usually implemented in full "numeric" class. Note: It may be useful to add sample of what you want to compile after your changes as there could be a different way around...

Comment: I get that, the point I am making is you can't just declare `System.String` and expect it to override the default, it doesn't work like that. You would need to completely remove your reference to `mscorlib.dll` otherwise your namespaces are going to clash.

Comment: @JoeWhite It's OK, read the note at the head of the question. (I don't need to actually execute the `.exe`.)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't need artificial integer, I just need to override it. (I don't need to actually execute the .exe.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have to not reference `mscorlib.dll`. Otherwise there will be two `System.String` classes, and clearly the predefined (C# Specification given) type `string` cannot be both of them.

See [`/nostdlib` C# compiler option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx). The page also describes how to do it with a setting in the Visual Studio IDE.

You need to write really many other required types (or copy-paste them) when you do not refer `mscorlib.dll`!

Comment: One question, when I will write in my code `123` the compiler will treat it as integer? (Quick answer can help, but I will have answer anyway in a few days.)

Comment: The compiler is required by the C# Language Specification to treat `123` as the predefined type `int`, which is `System.Int32`. If you write that type rather than just referring the mscorlib type, your type should be the "predefined" `int`. However I am not sure everything in the Common Language Runtime or elsewhere will work with your type. They may have "hard-coded" expectations to `int` which your "`int`" might violate.

Comment: I don't need the JIT to run the .NET EXE, I just need the EXE to extract the IL and make it run on the GPU\CUDA. It's to skip the lexer\parser part, and get right to the code generation part. Thanks by the way. I will wait for more answers anyway.

Comment: I checked the C# compiler's source code about that `int` part, and you are right. I doubted it because my situation is exceptional. You may add that part about `int`s.

Answer (score 3):

> Even a way to reach to csc.exe source code may help. (This is critical.)

Judging by your comments, this is actually the bit you *really* need. (Trying to change `int` and `string` themselves would involve changing `mscorlib` and almost certainly the CLR as well. Ouch.)

Fortunately, you're in luck: Microsoft has open-sourced [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), the next generation C# compiler that will ship with Visual Studio 2015.

If you want to change how the compiler behaves, you can fork the code and modify it appropriately. If you really just need to get at the abstract syntax tree (and the like) then you can do that without changing the compiler at all - Roslyn is design to be a "compiler API" rather than just a black-box which takes in source code and spits out IL. (As a mark of how rich the API is, Visual Studio 2015 uses the public API for everything - Intellisense, refactoring, etc.)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Why go to the trouble of changing a core library and then decompiling the code, rather than using the compiler to get at the relevant model before it's generated?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood the last paragraph (until now), I will look into it.